# Redirect SSH traffic through GRE tunnel

Tags: ssh, routing, tunnel, gre

I'm trying to redirect all local connections with destination matchs port 22 to specified tunnel using iptables MARK, but, something is going wrong.

```
1.1.1.1 my public address
2.2.2.2 tunnel public address
1.2.3.4 my local tunnel address
```

Here the configs:

```
# ip rule show 
1:      from all fwmark 0x14 lookup 20 

# ip route show table 20 
default via 1.2.3.4 dev tun0
```

And I have created following rules on iptables:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 20 
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j MARK --set-mark 20
```

And when I try to ssh some server(dreamhost in this case) I get:

```
tcp      6 299 ESTABLISHED src=1.1.1.1 dst=69.163.202.189 sport=37152 dport=22 packets=4 bytes=221 src=69.163.202.189 dst=1.1.1.1 sport=22 dport=37152 packets=2 bytes=133 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
```

Packet is not getting marked and going out through default route, which is 1.1.1.1

I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Anyone have any idea??

Answer (score 1):

**mangle's** *PREROUTING* is for altering *incoming packets* before routing and *OUTPUT* for altering *locally-generated packets* before routing. Hence *PREROUTING* is needless (for local connections). But `OUTPUT` should have worked, though. You don't need to specify source address in firewall rules usually, since it would be "locally-generated packets" anyway.

And another thing to remember is *no-one gonna change source IP just due to you've marked the packet and it would be routed with another route table — you'd need to use NAT explicitly for that*. In terms of Linux' iptables it has to be **SNAT**. And "This target is only valid in the nat table, in the POSTROUTING chain", as the man says. Although I personally prefer its subspecies `MASQUERADE` which is more handy for that, cause you don't have to bother with IP-addresses hard coding.

Comment: I've tryed -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 20 and now I got timed out. Looks like I really need SNAT, but I don't understand cleary why!

Comment: Since the difference is GRE adding a Header to each packet who leaves through this interface. And in fact, source address is the 1.1.1.1 and destination 2.2.2.2(the another edge) and inside the GRE packet we have the original source and destination. So why these marks are not working?

Comment: It has nothing to do with GRE in particular and encapsulation in general. It's just another route set, and that's it. `SNAT` has to be used due to IP packet had been already filled up and TCP/IP stack didn't use any policy routing when doing that.